# I want to create batch file and execute it using ActiveX object in VBScript on chrome and Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, vbscript, activex

I want to create batch file and execute it using ActiveX object in VBScript or JavaScript. It works fine in IE but not working in other browser.

```
set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MyFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\OPTICONRevit.bat",true)
MyFile.WriteLine("cd\")
MyFile.WriteLine(dirnm)
MyFile.WriteLine("cd " & sExePath)

MyFile.WriteLine("SEPL.Revit.exe " & chr(34) &  sPath & chr(34))
MyFile.close()
return1 = WshShell.run("C:\OPTICONRevit.bat",,true)
```

Comment: ActiveX is a Windows&IE only thing, and somewhat to most unsecure thing you could do with a browser today...

Comment: give me alternative to this for other browser.

Comment: alternative - a time machine back to when other browsers allowed this sort insecure crap

Comment: Where is the javascript called from? A file on the local harddrive, or via http/https?

Comment: @AndréSchild - It's being called from 1990's I beleive - and the code posted is VBScript, not JavaScript

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve. What do you need this for?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above in comments -- ActiveX is fully supported only in Internet Explorer web browser.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX

In 2015, Microsoft announced that their new web browser and Internet
Explorer replacement, **Microsoft Edge, will not support ActiveX, which
they described as a "legacy technology"**.

> ActiveX in non-Internet Explorer applications
>
> It may not always be possible to use Internet Explorer to execute
> ActiveX content (e.g. on a Wine installation), nor may a user want to.
>
> FF ActiveX Host can run ActiveX controls in Mozilla Firefox for
> Windows.
>
> Mozilla ActiveX Control was last updated in late 2005, and
> runs in Firefox 1.5.
>
> MediaWrap for Firefox was last updated on 12 June 2008, and will run in Firefox 1.5 to 3.5.*.

I personally checked these alternative solution for different browsers in Y2013 -- I get only bad experience.